# Magento 2: My custom plugin return 404 page in admin panel

Tags: magento2

I am trying to make my first plugin in Magento 2.0.2.
But magento admin panel show me 404 page.
I've read a few tutorials, but it does not help.

app/code/MyCustom/ProductsGroups/etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Products_Groups" setup_version="1.0.0">
    </module>
</config>
```

app/code/MyCustom/ProductsGroups/etc/adminhtml/menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Backend:etc/menu.xsd">
    <menu>
        <add id="Products_Groups::groups" title="Products groups" module="Products_Groups" parent="Magento_Catalog::inventory" action="groups/list/" resource="Products_Groups::groups"/>
    </menu>
</config>
```

app/code/MyCustom/ProductsGroups/etc/adminhtml/routes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="admin">
        <route id="groups" frontName="groups">
            <module name="Products_Groups"/>
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

app/code/MyCustom/ProductsGroups/Controller/Adminhtml/List/Index.php

```
<?php

namespace Axiom\Groups\Controller\Adminhtml\Groups;

class Index extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
    public function execute()
    {
        die ("test test test");
    }
}
```

Can some one help me?

Comment: I've fix this problem by change spacename to Magento/.. Looks like its hardcoded in Magento Module code.

Comment: I have the same problem, can you please point out where exactly you changed the namespace?

Comment: I found that all problems was with namespaces. The module name must be <company name>_<module name>, and all namespaces start with <company name>\<module name>\...